# Memory leak reading TZipFile

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

The following code creates a `.zip` file containing a text file named `HelloWord.txt`. Later, it reads the file correctly, **but a memory leak occurs** using `procedure Zipfile.Read (0, LStream, ZHeader)` **and releasing `LStream`**.

I am using `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;` to see memory leaks.

```pascal
// Uses  System.zip, System.IOUtils;
    
procedure Probezip;
var
  zipfile           : TZipFile;
  PathDoc           : string;
  LStream           : TStream;
  ZHeader           : TZipHeader;
  MyList            : TStringList;
begin
  // (Path documents windows)
  PathDoc := TPath.GetDocumentsPath;

  zipfile := TZipFile.Create;
  MyList  := TStringList.Create;


try
 // Write test TZipfile
  MyList.Add ('Hello Word');
  MyList.SaveToFile (PathDoc + '\' + 'helloword.txt');

  zipfile.Open (PathDoc + '\' + 'test.zip', zmWrite);
  ZipFile.Add (PathDoc + '\' + 'helloword.txt');
  ZipFile.Close;
  MyList.Clear;

  // Read test Tzipfile
  zipfile.Open (PathDoc + '\' + 'test.zip', zmRead);
  LStream := TStream.Create; //This line should be removed to solve the
                               // problem as Andreas Rejbrand has pointed out.
                               // I leave it here as a didactic value.
   try
     zipfile.Read (0, LStream, ZHeader);
      MyList.LoadFromStream (LStream);
      Showmessage (MyList.Text); // Hello Word
    finally
      LStream.Free;
   end;
  finally
    zipfile.Close;
    zipfile.Free;
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried your snippet in Seattle and no leaks. Can you share the fastMM leakreport?

Comment: I'm confused about your delphi version here, what is it? Tokyo 10.2 or delphi xe?

Comment: This is Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Version 25.0.29899.2631. After its note with Seattle, I tested it on version 10.4 Sydney and there are no memory leaks either. So I guess the code is correct and it's a bug in the compiler in version 10.2

Comment: @Silver: A bit off topic, perhaps, but I assume you would be more careful about your resources in a real application. (For instance, if `MyList.SaveToFile` raises an exception, `MyList` is leaked. In a real app, you always follow the idiom `X := TX.Create; try {use X} finally X.Free end` strictly unless you have very good reason not to.)

Comment: Your observation is true. Code updated to contain the protected operation in try finally. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter of the `TZipFile.Read` overload you are using is of type `TStream`, *but it is an `out` parameter*.

This means that the `TZipFile.Read` method *creates* a stream object and makes `LStream` point to it. Hence, you leak the stream you created manually on the line before. Remove that line (`LStream := TStream.Create;`) and move down the `try` protecting the stream:

```
zipfile.Read(0, LStream, ZHeader); // will CREATE a stream object
                                   // and save its address in LStream
try
  MyList.LoadFromStream(LStream);
  Showmessage(MyList.Text); // Hello Word
finally
  LStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Besides, `LStream := TStream.Create;` was wrong anyway, since `TStream` is an *abstract class* and should *never* be created directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Indeed, very true.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Indeed, his recommendation solves the problem completely. Thank you very much for your interesting notes regarding the output parameters, I had not seen this. Marking your answer as a valid solution!!. Thank you all in general for the code review and your valuable comments.